# why is QVector implementation in header and cpp is empty

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style

Mainly curious about coding style - why is it sometimes better to place implementation in header like for example QVector:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h

the cpp is totaly empty

Comment: Template implementations have to be in the header file, unless you want to go to quite a bit of extra effort to save a bit of compile time.

Comment: thanks, so its about templates.. I barely used them - not coding containers..